# How to model user transactions for DB storage in a small chat app?

Tags: c++, database, qt, chat

I am trying to develop my own simple chat app using Qt5.

**Some Context**
What I have until now is a simple server that will receive any messages from users (that are using the corresponding client) and store them in a database, together with a **from**, **to** and **iseRead** field.

Then the clients regularly ask the server for message updates (I know this is probably not a good idea but I am not sure I know how to find who is online using Qt so please disregard it) and receive those messages that are meant for them.

What I want do now is add the ability for a user to not have to specifically choose someone else from the list to message but broadcast something to all. Adding a *ALL* value to my **to** column will not help as I do not know when to mark the **isRead** field for that message and this result in users receiving it constantly at every client request.

Also things become more complex if I wanted to add the ability to message a group of people.

**The Real Question**
How can I structure my server-side database to efficiently store and retrieve the user transactions I've described above (send messages to individuals, broadcast to all, to groups, etc)?

Comment: It is OK, that server sends data only by request. One of solution is to send some kind of ping (keep alive) from client with some interval. And if server will not receive ping information - then client is disconnected.

Comment: It is not clear, what you mean by `database` and why you need it to exchange messages?

Comment: @SaZ I'm thinking he wants to store messages server side for the sake of offline messaging.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire I think so too. But question is too broad.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire well yeah that was the idea. Every message you send gets stored in a posture database, and when you want to check for new messages you receive only those meant for you. As for the question being broad as you can understand the gist of it is the last sentence, all the rest is just explaining the situation.

Comment: @dearn44 I think the question is too broad. I mean, it seems on the surface to be a simple "how should I structure my database" but really since the database is sort of serving as a foundational structure that is defining of and dependent on your overall architecture, it's... well it's pretty damn broad. Any decent answer will end up writing a framework for a chat service.

Comment: If you put it like that then indeed it is true, maybe the question should be edited because all I care about is a sort of a general guideline on how I should store in the datable information on who is talking to who. I obviously do not want the actual implementation of such a system.

Comment: Do not worry on the who is online part, I can fix that later, and just mentioned it to give a reason as to why I am using *to* and *from* fields in my database.

Comment: I meant postgre above, not posture obviously.

Comment: @dearn44 I posted an off-the-top-of-my-head answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this, off the top of my head.

```
Users Table    
unique_user_id, user_specific_info1, user_specific_info2, so on..

Messages Table
message, target_user_id, sender_id, message_status
```

Now I wouldn't even bother storing sessions or group messages and whatnot in the database. That's just extra overhead for no reason. Have minimal server side code to allow users to add eachother to a chat and let the client sofware handle who is invited into the room and such. Then have the client send a message with the relevant data: target_user_ids, the message, the senders id.

In the server side logic, get the message, parse out the target user_ids, create a new entry into the messages table for each of the target user_id's and set the status to UNREAD, flip the status to READ once your server software has succesfully transmitted the message data to the target user id.

Simple. This solves all your questions of group chat messages, broadcasting to absolutely everyone, etc.

**Update**
Now obviously you're going to want to optimize this. As an example, you probably really don't want to duplicate and store the data for every message to every user on a broadcast, so this is where you'd create a standalone `Messages` table that holds the raw message content with an auto-incrementing unique index, and then maybe have a second Message Status table that's like this instead:

```
Messages Status Table
message_id, target_user_id, sender_id, message_status
```

Now you can have 10000000 people get the same message but you're only storing a reference to the ID of the message 10000000 times, not the whole message data. You could then also have a cron job then run on your server once daily or something to purge all messages with the status READ from your system to avoid bloat.

Comment: This indeed seems like a good way of going about this, and it is not too afar from what I originally tried to do. +1 for the letting the client deal with groups suggestion. What only worries me a little bit is all these read and write from the various tables operations. Not for a particular reason, I have no idea if it will be slow or not. But I guess nothing comes for free.

Comment: @dearn44 There is always an expense. I think this is a decent starting point to at least get your application functional. Once you're there, you can move on to trying to optimize things more. I think if you keep things simple and you're indexing this data in separate tables by simple unique id's, you're going to get the best performance one can hope for.

Comment: On another note, if you're just doing this setup for offline messages, you could have the server simply act as a connection negotiator and have the clients bypass these operations in the server by simply reading and writing directly to eachother. Then if the client fails to deliver a message directly, it sends the data to be stored and looked up by the server later. Don't be afraid to delegate to the client. Trying to push everything to the server's workload is a total waste of the computing power your user has to offer. :)

Comment: I was not complaining .)
Already started implementing this because as you said its a decent starting point. Ill use the row number as a unique id, uuid would be an overkill I guess.

Comment: I cannot do that yet, I don't know how to make the clients communicate that way. Id have to make them act as a server too, listening for new messages.

Comment: @dearn44 All I could do there is point you to boost::asio, which has to be the easiest and most portable cross platform socket IO library I know of. Also has a bajillion code samples. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/

Comment: BOOST is getting in my way almost constantly lately, I should really familiarise myself with it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to register all users that are online. That is when client first connect and authenticate you would add entry with clients nick to table *online* of form [pk, user_nick] for example. The reverse you would do when client goes out(remove from online).
Then when a ALL message is sent from client you check whats in *online* and add entries for all clients nicks from *online* table to your table where you store messages ~ which was [from, to, isRead].

The group feature in your case - add table *groups* [pk, id_group, nick]. You have to implement logic for client to know what are possible groups identified by id_group. Then client would write a message to id_group and server would check what users are in that group (select .. where id_group=x) and repeat the message into your messages table (that one with from, to, isRead)

You said you do not know how to find out who is online - usually you implement some login mechanism - when client first connect you store his IP, source port or anything to identify him along with his nick.. in this way you know who is online.. of course you have to implement also logout and optionally some timeout mechanism if client is inactive then log him out.
In this way you would have some array of opened connections and when client A write message to client B you would simply proxy the message to B.. in this way it would be much easier to implement additional features.

**Update - adding example**

I would move the logic from online table to new table User to store details about user and to ease the process of authentication  etc.

Chat [pk, (fk) fromU , (fk) toU, isRead] #the fk = foreign keys to user pk

User [pk, Nick, Logged]

Group [pk, group_id, (fk) user_id] #little bit nasty, but simple we would repeat the group_id ..

We have this in User:

1, John, true

2, Eva, true

3, Jana, true

Then when Eva sends ALL message "hello" we would add three entries to Chat table:

54, 2, 1, "Hello"

55, 2, 2, "Hello" #this is optional, in this way also Eva would see her own chat, which is sometimes ok, you do not have to handle this extra in your app..

56, 2, 3, "Hello"

Then when John is checking messages he would do:
Select * from Chat where toU=1;

Very similarly we would do the group feature.

Comment: So basically you are saying I should have another table storing all the various groups that users might create identified by an id right?
But then when a client is checking for new messages what it needs to know is in what groups is its name mentioned, so Im afraid holding a list of names somewhere in a field won't help. I am not all that good with databases but if I say **WHERE to = somename** and **somename** is a list of names it won't work.

Comment: @dearn44 First question - yes. I am not sure if I understand you now.. the user which is checking new messages for him would be checking just table messages where he would already have messages incoming from any groups.. maybe you are asking how the user would know from which group the message came?

Comment: There is only one table, and the way I check for messages is something like 
**SELECT * FROM Chat WHERE (toU = :username OR toU = 'ALL') AND (isRead = false)"**
which makes the idea of holding the groups a bit hard to implement.

Comment: well in my answer I suggest you create two more tables _online_ and _groups_ the structure of Chat table (which I was calling messages) would remain the same and you wouldnt need the 'ALL' hack, I will update with example.

Comment: Yes I know but maybe I did not completely understood how the groups table would work.

Comment: I see, this also solves the groups issue in a quite similar way as Technik Empire suggested. Thanks for your answer and sorry for not getting it at first.